# Can't `brew search` due to "definition is invalid" error

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

Running `brew search gcc` results in the following error with no results.

```bash
Error: Cask 'portfolioperformance' definition is invalid: invalid 'sha256' value: {:arm=>"a100a3601af46c2e7e79f0dc129fce4da7ebf0cc594d795ac17a4aaa418941a9", :intel=>"5bd97c6742036dd5d13dd4badd51672720e470f7f657d8069b4a7da1fda62ba3"}
```

I don't have this cask installed. `brew doctor` doesn't show anything unexpected.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Can you

```
brew update
```

and then try again?